# Javascript regex validate password string (escaping punctuations)

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping, punctuation

I am trying to validate a password string with javascript and need some help with a regex. I have tried some tutorials, but I think I have some problems understanding how to escape quantifiers and/or metacharacters.

I want to make sure that the password string only contains one or more (max 32) characters from the following spans:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"012345678901234567890123456789"
"!@#%&/(){}[]=?+*^~-_.:,;"
```

The first three spans are pretty easy, but I can't figure out the last one. Basically my script looks something like this:

```
var password = "user_input_password";

if (/^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%...]{1,32}$/.test(password)) {
    document.write('OK');
} else {
    document.write('Not OK');
}
```

Any help or input is highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can escape a meta-character using a backslash `\`; however, inside a character class, the only ones you have to escape are `]` , `\` and `-` (the `^` only has a meaning at the very beginning). Something like `[\w!@#%&/(){}[\]=?+*^~\-.:,;]` will do what you want.

The `\w` is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

So the full test would be something like:

```
/^[\w!@#%&/(){}[\]=?+*^~\-.:,;]{1,32}$/.test(password)
```

Comment: you also need to espace "-" symbol. it defines range inside [].

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I even noted that in my answer, but left it out of the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9!@#%&\/(){}\[\]=?+*^~\-_\.:,;]{1,32}$/
```

Comment: I don't think you need to escape the `[` or `.` or `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also match all characters that are not considered white space (space, newline, tab)

```
/^[^\s]{1,32}$/.test(password);
```

To exclude quotes as well (I didn't see them in your example) you can add those in:

```
/^[^\s'"]{1,32}$/.test(password);
```